# Why doesn't 'ZonedTime' have an 'Eq' or 'Ord' instance

Tags: haskell, time

In the [`time`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time) package we have the type `ZonedTime` which represents a `LocalTime` a product of `localDay :: Day` and `localTimeOfDay :: TimeOfDay`. `LocalTime` has instances for `Eq` and `Ord`, but `ZonedTime` does not. It seems to me that `ZonedTime`s ought to be compared from an absolute reference frame still—at least as much as `LocalTime`s could be.

Why doesn't `ZonedTime` have `Eq` and `Ord` instances as well?

It's worth noting that the `time` rewrite [`thyme`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/thyme) actually does have `Eq` and `Ord` instances, though I'd prefer not to use non-standard time types unless needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only speculate that the reason is that it is not entirely clear how times that have different zones attached should be compared, and it is easy enough to convert them to `UTCTime` using `zonedTimeToUTC` and compare the results if that's what's intended.

Comment: I suppose I just assumed observational equality under `zonedTimeToUTC`, yeah. I also noticed `thyme` just uses intrinsic equality and both `time` and `thyme` define intrinsic equality over `TimeZone`s to have both exactly identical offsets and also names.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is due to daylight savings? Like, sometimes UK time = French time, but at other times of the year there's a 1-hour difference...